# Changing color in horizontal line in a table

Tags: tables

The following code

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}

\definecolor{orangec}{RGB}{255,158,62}

\newcommand{\wh}{\color{white}}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|}
\arrayrulecolor{orange}
\hline
\rowcolor{orange}\multicolumn{3}{|l|}{\wh\textit{\textbf{some}} \textbf{y} \textit{\textbf{any}}} \\ 
\multicolumn{3}{|l|}{Usamos some en oraciones afirmativas y any en oraciones} \\ 
\multicolumn{3}{|l|}{negativas y preguntas.} \\ 
\multicolumn{1}{!{\color{orange}\vline} l !{\color{white}\vline}}{\cellcolor{orange}} 
  & \multicolumn{1}{c !{\color{white}\vline}}{\cellcolor{orange}\color{white}\textbf{s.i.}} & \multicolumn{1}{c !{\color{orange}\vline}}{\cellcolor{orange}\color{white}\textbf{s.c.}}   \\ 
\hline
\multicolumn{1}{!{\color{orange}\vline} l !{\color{orange}\vline}}{\cellcolor{orangec}\wh\textbf{afirmativo}} 
  & \multicolumn{1}{l !{\color{orange}\vline}}{\cellcolor{white}There's some beef.} & \multicolumn{1}{l !{\color{orange}\vline}}{\cellcolor{white}There are some eggs.}   \\
\hline
\multicolumn{1}{!{\color{orange}\vline} l !{\color{orange}\vline}}{\cellcolor{orangec}\wh\textbf{negativo}} 
  & \multicolumn{1}{l !{\color{orange}\vline}}{\cellcolor{white}There isn't any beef.} & \multicolumn{1}{l !{\color{orange}\vline}}{\cellcolor{white}There aren't any eggs.}   \\
\hline
\multicolumn{1}{!{\color{orange}\vline} l !{\color{orange}\vline}}{\cellcolor{orangec}\wh\textbf{interrogativo}} 
  & \multicolumn{1}{l !{\color{orange}\vline}}{\cellcolor{white}Is there any beef?} & \multicolumn{1}{l !{\color{orange}\vline}}{\cellcolor{white}Are there any eggs?}   \\
\hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Gives

[image]

However I can't get white lines in the following image:

[image]

As you can see, those lines are orange-colored. I want them white. What's the way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{hhline}

\definecolor{orangec}{RGB}{255,158,62}

\newcommand{\wh}{\color{white}}

\begin{document}
\sffamily

\setlength\arrayrulewidth{1pt}
\begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|}
\arrayrulecolor{orange}
\hline
\rowcolor{orange}\multicolumn{3}{|l|}{\wh\textit{\textbf{some y any}}} \\ 
\multicolumn{3}{|l|}{Usamos some en oraciones afirmativas y any en oraciones} \\ 
\multicolumn{3}{|l|}{negativas y preguntas.} \\ 
\multicolumn{1}{!{\color{orange}\vline} l !{\color{white}\vline}}{\cellcolor{orange}} 
  & \multicolumn{1}{c !{\color{white}\vline}}{\cellcolor{orange}\color{white}\textbf{s.i.}} & \multicolumn{1}{c !{\color{orange}\vline}}{\cellcolor{orange}\color{white}\textbf{s.c.}}   \\ 
\hhline{>{\arrayrulecolor{white}}->{\arrayrulecolor{orange}}--}%\hline
\multicolumn{1}{!{\color{orange}\vline} l !{\color{orange}\vline}}{\cellcolor{orangec}\wh\textbf{afirmativo}} 
  & \multicolumn{1}{l !{\color{orange}\vline}}{\cellcolor{white}There's some beef.} & \multicolumn{1}{l !{\color{orange}\vline}}{\cellcolor{white}There are some eggs.}   \\
\hhline{>{\arrayrulecolor{white}}->{\arrayrulecolor{orange}}--}%\hline
\multicolumn{1}{!{\color{orange}\vline} l !{\color{orange}\vline}}{\cellcolor{orangec}\wh\textbf{negativo}} 
  & \multicolumn{1}{l !{\color{orange}\vline}}{\cellcolor{white}There isn't any beef.} & \multicolumn{1}{l !{\color{orange}\vline}}{\cellcolor{white}There aren't any eggs.}   \\
\hhline{>{\arrayrulecolor{white}}->{\arrayrulecolor{orange}}--}%\hline
\multicolumn{1}{!{\color{orange}\vline} l !{\color{orange}\vline}}{\cellcolor{orangec}\wh\textbf{interrogativo}} 
  & \multicolumn{1}{l !{\color{orange}\vline}}{\cellcolor{white}Is there any beef?} & \multicolumn{1}{l !{\color{orange}\vline}}{\cellcolor{white}Are there any eggs?}   \\
\hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Using the `hhline` package you can easily control the colors of different segments of the `\hline`. I used the syntax,

```
\hhline{>{\arrayrulecolor{white}}->{\arrayrulecolor{orange}}--}
```

The number of dashes `->` or `--` after the specified color refer to the number of `\cline`s with that color.

Note that I changed `\arrayrulewidth` to `1pt` because PDFReader may show the rules very thin or unequal in thickness as it assumes that orange shading is more important than the white rules.